# What is the error talking about?

Tags: php, mysql, database

well i am new to php .Now all i am trying to do is insert some data in a database table.

Here is the sample code

```
<?php 
include("DbMethods.php");
connectToDb();

$name=$_POST['name'];
$location=$_POST['location'];
$item=$_POST['item'];


    $result=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `customer` WHERE `name`='".$name."' AND `location`='".$location."' AND `item`='".$item."')")or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

and this is what the error looks like

```
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
```

What exactly is wrong?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Please [Prevent SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)

Comment: What is your intended purpose for that random unmatched `')`?

Comment: Thank you so uch for your suggestion:)I will see how to use prepared statements:)

Answer (score 3):

You have an erroneous `)` at the end of your query. The error message is pretty explicit about this.

```
$result=mysql_query(" ... AND `item`='".$item."')")or die(mysql_error());
                                                ^
```

As mentioned in the comments, **please stop using `mysql_` functions**. Why? For one reason someone may submit `'; DROP customer` for `item`.

Answer (score 0):

`...$item."')")or die...` should be `...$item."'")or die...` which means it can't find a matching parentheses which is why it is giving you that error

Answer (score 0):

Dont use mysql_*...

remove the extra )

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `customer` WHERE `name`='".$name."' AND `location`='".$location."' AND `item`='".$item."'")or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line with the following:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `customer` WHERE `name`='".$name."' AND `location`='".$location."' AND `item`='".$item."') or die(mysql_error());
```

Error is actually stating that there is syntax error near ')' character. Quite specific and clear error message ;)

And as it was already mentioned, don't use mysql_ ever again.